# Using ORDER BY clause to order a query by using values selected from a drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, switch-statement

I want to use a dropdown list to order the query result. Whatever option is chosen in the dropdown list, the query will be ordered in ascending order by the option selected. My query works fine, I just need to include the ORDER BY clause which I know comes after the WHERE clause. Please look at the form carefully and please help me on this problem.

Below is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Exam Interface</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<form action="exam_interface.php" method="post" name="sessionform">        <!-- This will post the form to its own page"-->
<p>Session ID: <input type="text" name="sessionid" /></p>      <!-- Enter Session Id here-->
<p>Module Number: <input type="text" name="moduleid" /></p>      <!-- Enter Module Id here-->
<p>Teacher Username: <input type="text" name="teacherid" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher here-->
<p>Student Username: <input type="text" name="studentid" /></p>      <!-- Enter User Id here-->
<p>Grade: <input type="text" name="grade" /></p>      <!-- Enter Grade here-->
<p>Order Results By: <select name="order">
<option name="noorder">Don't Order Results</option>
<option name="ordersessionid">Session ID</option>
<option name="ordermoduleid">Module Number</option>
<option name="orderteacherid">Teacher Username</option>
<option name="orderstudentid">Student Username</option>
<option name="ordergrade">Grade</option>
</select>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="mobile_app";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$sessionid = $_POST['sessionid'];
$moduleid = $_POST['moduleid'];
$teacherid = $_POST['teacherid'];
$studentid = $_POST['studentid'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Module m INNER JOIN Session s ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId WHERE ('$sessionid' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '$sessionid') AND ('$moduleid' = '' OR m.ModuleId = '$moduleid') AND ('$teacherid' = '' OR s.TeacherId = '$teacherid') AND ('$studentid' = '' OR gr.StudentId = '$studentid') AND ('$grade' = '' OR gr.Grade = '$grade')");

$num=mysql_numrows($result);    

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Student Id</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Session Id</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Mark</th>
<th>Module</th>
<th>Teacher</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['StudentId'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Forename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SessionId'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Grade'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Mark'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ModuleName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['TeacherId'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close();


 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using a switch statement which was kindly posted to me but I couldn't get it to work. This is what I tried to do below:

```
$orderfield = isset ($_POST['order']);
switch ($orderfield) {
    case 'ordersessionid': $orderfield = 'gr.SessionId';
    break;
    case 'ordermoduleid': $orderfield = 'm.ModuleId'; 
    break;
    case 'orderteacherid': $orderfield = 's.TeacherId';
    break;
    case 'orderstudentid': $orderfield = 'gr.StudentId'; 
    break;
    case 'ordergrade': $orderfield = 'gr.Grade';
    break;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Module m INNER JOIN Session s ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId WHERE ('$sessionid' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '$sessionid') AND ('$moduleid' = '' OR m.ModuleId = '$moduleid') AND ('$teacherid' = '' OR s.TeacherId = '$teacherid') AND ('$studentid' = '' OR gr.StudentId = '$studentid') AND ('$grade' = '' OR gr.Grade = '$grade') ORDER BY '$orderfield' ASC");
```

Any help will be much appriciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$orderfield = isset ($_POST['order']) ? $_POST['order'] : 'default order field';
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

### Update

Just noticed... arguments to the `ORDER BY` statements aren't parameters but expressions. In other words, lose the single-quotes around `$orderfield` in your query, ie

```
... ORDER BY $orderfield ASC");
```

Comment: @user992147 See my updated answer. Also see Mike B's answer for another problem in your markup

Comment: Almost there it has ordered the rows but problem is that no matter which option I select from the dropdown list it only orders by sessionid. How do I get it to order the table depending on the values selected from the drop down list

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might have put the wrong attribute on those options. You want value, not name:

```
<option value="noorder">Don't Order Results</option>
```

---

#### Or... Debug

Find out why it's not working:

```
$orderfield = isset ($_POST['order']);
switch ($orderfield) {
    case 'ordersessionid': $orderfield = 'gr.SessionId';
    break;
    case 'ordermoduleid': $orderfield = 'm.ModuleId'; 
    break;
    case 'orderteacherid': $orderfield = 's.TeacherId';
    break;
    case 'orderstudentid': $orderfield = 'gr.StudentId'; 
    break;
    case 'ordergrade': $orderfield = 'gr.Grade';
    break;
}

// Debug here by checking the value of $orderfield
// This will tell us if the switch statement did its job
var_dump($orderfield);

// Alternatively, you could set a default case and catch it there
```

You can also inspect the `$_POST` array before all this happens. Give this a look and see if all your form values are there:

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

Comment: Good catch on the `name` attribute mistake

Comment: I used echo to output what $orderfield is outputting. All it is outputting is the value gr.SessionId, If I select another value from drop down menu and submit it, it doesn't change, still says gr.SessionId.

Comment: I'd also: 1) echo your "select" statement before calling mysql_query(), and 2) manually cut/paste the same select stmt into mysql to see if it executes correctly when you run it by hand.  I think the actual string is VERY different from what you think it is :)!